# Grails 2.x REST Controller - works in empty project, not the 'real' project

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am fairly sure I have something simple setup incorrectly in my project, but I sure could use some help finding out what!

I have the latest GGTS and Grails 2.4.3.  I tried to make a REST Controller in a project that two of us are working on.  As this was new to me, when it didn't work, I found an article that showed how simple it was and followed it exactly in a new, empty project.  Everything worked properly and as advertised!  I used grails commands to create the project, the domain class and then the controller.

I went back to my original project and did the same steps (except for creating the project which already existed, but WAS created via the grails command).  Instead of working, when I hit the rest URL via a GET it returns a HTTP 404 status and a message saying that it can not find 'index.gsp'.  Of course, index.gsp does not exist.  However, it should return json as requested.  My question is why?

Since I am (now) just trying to get the REST calls working, the Domain class is trivial - three String fields.  No other relationships.  The Controller extends RestfulController.  No static scaffold or anything like that....

*What is the same in each project?*

Most of the setup is original and untouched.  Both the URLMapping files are identical.  Both of the Config.groovy files are identical.

*What is different between the two projects?*

The main difference is that three (3) non-REST controllers already exist.  This is far and away the biggest difference that I see.  Is there an issue / need to configure something when 'mixing' Controllers (REST and nonRest) or should they peacefully co-exist?

The only other difference is the existing project (that does not work) has AngularJS and Bootstrap.  Nothing else has been added.

Any ideas appreciated!

**Gory details**

The curl command used to hit the endpoint:

```
curl  -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/myproject/example
```

response:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 - Error report</title><style><!--H1
[deleted font family lines...]
{color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style>
</head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - &quot;/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/example/index.gsp&quot; not found.</h1>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b>
<u>&quot;/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/example/index.gsp&quot; not found.</u></p><p> 
<b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>ApacheTomcat/7.0.55</h3></body></html>
```

Domain Class:

```
package com.mycompany.rest

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode;
import groovy.transform.ToString;

@ToString(includeNames = true, includeFields = true, excludes = 'dateCreated, lastUpdated')
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Example {

    Long id
    Long version
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    String name
    String description


    static constraints = {
        name blank:false, nullable:false
        description blank:false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.mycompany.rest

import grails.rest.RestfulController;

class ExampleController extends RestfulController<Example> {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    ExampleController() {
            super(Example)
    }


}
```

Comment: When everything seems like it should work but doesn't, and especially when you make a change that should have a small effect but things end up  behaving weirdly, run `grails clean` and `grails compile` and then try again. You can also `rm -rf target` to delete installed plugins and all compiled code and then `grails compile` force a full requild. Sometimes the dynamic code gets out of sync and you need to rebuild everything cleanly

Comment: Also, unrelated - you should omit `Long id` and `Long version` since those are added by the Grails compiler for you. No harm having them there, but they're clutter. Also `nullable:false` is the default for all properties, so no need for that, and Grails 2.4 replaces blank strings with nulls during databinding, so you can probaly delete `blank:false` also. And lose those semicolons :)

Comment: You don't want `id`, `version`, `lastUpdated`, or `dateCreated` to factor into `hashCode` or `equals` calculation - I'm guessing that 2 instances with the same `name` and `description` would be considered 'equal' (or even 2 with the same `name`), but a difference in the other 4 props is likely and would defeat bothering to calculate `hashCode`/`equals` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I never figured out exactly what was causing the behavior I described, it was obviously something strange I did in the original project somewhere!

I resolved the issue by creating a third brand new, empty project.  I added my rest service as described above and verified that worked - naturally it did.  Then, because the work thus far was still not very large, I copied each controller/domain object/view/etc into the new project.  Everything now works.  Kind of a wimpy way to resolve the issue I know, but as I suspect I somehow put the first project into a highly unlikely state anyway, I am just happy to be back functional!

Also - thanks Burt for the other comments - have incorporated them all.